# Having issues with postgresql, what should I log?

Tags: postgresql, logging

Here's the error message I am receiving.

```
could not translate host name "localhost" to address: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
```

From my searching, it seems like postgresql has crashed due to an error. If a proper shutdown is initiated, the message is different.

```
FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
```

So I know it's not a proper shutdown of the database service that is occurring.

I am logging to syslog on a FreeBSD system. The log is very basic and essentially only shows me shutdown and startup attempts.

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-05-08 09:20:16 EDT
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I am currently using default logging options. What do I need to change in order for PostgreSQL to log errors?

**Requested Information**

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1               localhost localhost.my.domain
```

DB connection code:

```
char conninfo[] = "host=localhost port=xxx dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx";
conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);
if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK) {
print error
}
```

Comment: Can you `ping localhost`? Are you getting that error from the `psql`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll yes I can ping localhost. The database connects for some time before it reaches this error. I am printing this error in C code using libpq. The error happens after a few days of the server being on.

Comment: And if you change listen_addresses = '[to your real IP address]' in postgresql.conf, and connect to the database using that IP address, do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

```
could not translate host name "localhost" to address
```

Implies a failure in your DNS resolver. You can see the error generated in [libpq's fe-connect.c :1661](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/fe-connect_8c.html#ab3bd9072bdf2a88812f671369b776473). There is a call to [`pg_getaddrinfo_all`](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/ip_8c.html#afe2ba16bf139ac4b1b59912923350875) which is a wrapper for `getaddrinfo` which is provided by `glibc`.

See man `getaddrinfo`.

Does your local `/etc/hosts` file have an entry for localhost, or are you relying on a remote DNS server to resolve localhost to `127.0.0.1`? What are you providing in `PGConn` to `connectDBStart`?

Comment: There's no remote DNS setup and there is an entry in my hosts file (I'll add that to the original post). I can ping localhost just fine and the C code can connect to the server and will stay connected for days/weeks/etc. I'll add the connect info to the original post as well.